# Find the limit of function $f_{n}(x) = nx^{n}$

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

Show that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} nx^{n} = 0$ for $x \in [0, 1), n \in \mathbb{N}$

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} nx^{n}$

$\Rightarrow \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} n \cdot \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} x^{n}$

$\Rightarrow \infty * 0$

$\Rightarrow 0$

Is this correct?

Now show that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{0}^{1} f_{n}(x) dx = 1$

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{0}^{1} nx^{n} dx$

$\Rightarrow \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{n}{n + 1} x^{n + 1}$

(then plug in $1$ and $0$ into $x$)

$\Rightarrow \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{2}x^2$

Which is not $=1$, where did I go wrong?

Comment: Your first deduction is not correct. You cannot use 'limit of products = product of limits' if the individual limits don't exist. Further, for your second point, you plugged 0,1 in for $n$, not for $x$.

Comment: Additionally, your use of the implication symbol $\Rightarrow$ is wrong: as written, it does not mean anything (or, in any case, not what you are thinking).

Comment: For the second part, now I get $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{n}{n + 1} = 1$. Is this right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have noted, even if $0\cdot\infty$ was defined (and it isn't), you still couldn't just break up the product inside the limit. Instead, you could apply L'Hoptial's rule to get:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{x^{-n}} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{-x^{-n}\log x}=0$$

Answer (score -2):

$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left(nx^n \right)=
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left(n \over x^{-n} \right)=
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left(1 \over (-n)x^{-n-1} \right)=
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left(-x^{n+1} \over n \right)=0\;  (for\;\; 0\leq x<1)
$$

Comment: Why -1? I want to say that @nbubis is right but the last step is wrong. Isn't it?

Comment: To apply l'Hospital you need to differentiate with respect to the variable tending to infinity. You differentiated w.r.t. $n$ in the numerator and w.r.t. $x$ in the denominator, so this is nonsense.

Comment: I see. Thanks. JL you are very helpful. I should be more careful.